# Powerslide trinity frames: ego vs elite

Tags: equipment, inline-skating

What is practical (in terms of skating) difference between two Powerslide trinity frames [Ego SL](https://www.powerslide.com/Powerslide-Frame-Trinity-Ego-SL-243mm-3x110) and [Elite Al casted](https://www.powerslide.com/Powerslide-Elite-AL-Casted-96-243mm-3x110mm-black)? According to specs both frames are made of aluminium, Ego is CNC milled and Elite is casted. It is said [somewhere](https://bladeville.com/blog/powerslide-trinity-frames-which-one-to-choose) about Elite frames:

> Thanks to the very low design of the frames with Trinity mount, the frames made with this technology do not differ much in rigidity from the CNC frames.

which sounds to me as there would be nearly no difference riding one or another. Am I correct or have I missed something?